# error message Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hello guys this is the following query I have, I am trying to convert binary(8) to datetime but I get the following error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Can you please help me out.

```
DECLARE @VarBinary VarBinary(10)
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME

SET @VarBinary = CAST(CAST('1998/01/24' AS DATETIME) AS VARBINARY(10))
SET @DateTime = @VarBinary

SELECT TOP 1000 [NodeId],[NodePropertyId],[NodePropertyValue],convert(datetime2, [TStamp]),[Source],[LoadDate]
FROM [Fleet_Staging].[dbo].[rdex_NodePropertyValues]
```

Comment: Presumably one or more `[TStamp]` cannot be converted to `datetime2` - The query itself does not even make use of @DateTime/@VarBinary

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `[TStamp]` is correct ,If something is wrong you can get this error.For example below code give same error.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, '2011-09-28 18:01:00 xxx')
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I'm trying to convert the following select statement, but it says cannot convert and the column name I'm trying to convert is [TStamp].    SELECT TOP 1000
 [NodeId]
 ,[NodePropertyId]
 ,[NodePropertyValue]
 ,convert(datetime2, [TStamp]),
 [Source],[LoadDate]
FROM [Fleet_Staging].[dbo].[rdex_NodePropertyValues]

Answer (score 0):

Error Before **[TStamp]**

There is no error in English Language

```
DECLARE @VarBinary VarBinary(10)
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME
SET LANGUAGE English  
SET @VarBinary = CAST(CAST('1998/01/24' AS DATETIME) AS VARBINARY(10))
SET @DateTime = @VarBinary
SELECT @VarBinary
```

If, I Change Language; There is same Error with you in Turkish language.

```
DECLARE @VarBinary VarBinary(10)
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME
SET LANGUAGE Turkish  
SET @VarBinary = CAST(CAST('1998/01/24' AS DATETIME) AS VARBINARY(10))
SET @DateTime = @VarBinary
SELECT @VarBinary
```

> varchar veri türünden bir datetime veri türüne dönüştürme aralık dışı bir değerle sonuçlandı.

USE Convert Function [See Microsoft Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) OR [W3 Schools Page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

```
DECLARE @VarBinary VarBinary(10)
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME 
SET LANGUAGE Turkish
SET @VarBinary = CAST(convert(DATETIME, '1998/01/24',111 ) AS VARBINARY(10))
SET LANGUAGE English
SET @VarBinary = CAST(convert(DATETIME, '1998/01/24',111 ) AS VARBINARY(10)) 
SET @DateTime = @VarBinary
SELECT @VarBinary
```

No ERROR

Answer (score 0):

```
set dateformat YMD
```

before SET @Varbinary = CAST(convert....

should works! :)